# TCPSocket.send: What happens when the buffer is full?

Tags: javascript, tcp, firefox-os, tcpsocket

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket.send) of `TCPSocket.send`:

> - If send returns `true`, then less than 64k has been buffered and it's safe to immediately
>     write more.
> - If send returns `false`, then more than 64k has been buffered, and the caller may wish to
>     wait until the drain event has been triggered before buffering more data by more calls to
>     send.

This tells the program what best to do *next* in order to avoid a buffer overflow.

*What happens if the buffer is **already** full? Can the program check whether the buffer is full **before** sending data?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this but have you looked at the  TCPSocket.bufferedAmount property?
[TCP Socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/TCP_Socket).  From this article: "It's possible to know exactly the current amount of data buffered with the TCPSocket.bufferedAmount property."